# Individual Cells In VBA Code Do Not Paste Correctly

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code which moves data in the active row/s along so that there are gaps on the row as required.
It then copied formulas out of row 6 to fill those gaps.

However, when the copied cell is just an individual cell rather than a range, instead of pasting the formula in the corresponding cell in the active row it pastes the data from that 1 cell on row 6 across the previous copied range in the active row.
I.E. If copied 3 cells from row 6, 3 cells pasted into active row. Then copy 1 cell from row 6, 3 cells pasted into active row. -This should only be 1 pasted.

Here is the code:

```
Sub DeliveryDriverDataAdjust()
    
    Application.Calculation = xlManual 'Formulas are not calculated
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'What the user see's on screen will not change
    
    With Selection.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1 - Selection.Column) 'Does everything based off of column A.
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight 'Inserts X to the right of column A in the active row.
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=12).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=13).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=14).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=15).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=16).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=20).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=22).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=23).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=27).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=28).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=29).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=33).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=34).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=35).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=37).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=38).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=39).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=40).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=43).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=44).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=45).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=46).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=47).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=48).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=49).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=50).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=51).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=52).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=53).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=54).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=55).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=57).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    End With
        
        Range("B6:C6").Copy 'Copies a specific cell/s
        With Selection.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1 - Selection.Column) 'Does everything based off of Column A.
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).PasteSpecial 'Pastes X to the right of column A in the active row.
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Clears what is being copied.
        
        Range("M6:Q6").Copy 'Copies a specific cell/s
        With Selection.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1 - Selection.Column) 'Does everything based off of Column A.
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=12).PasteSpecial 'Pastes X to the right of column A in the active row.
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Clears what is being copied.
        
        Range("U6").Copy 'Copies a specific cell/s
        With Selection.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1 - Selection.Column) 'Does everything based off of Column A.
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=20).PasteSpecial 'Pastes X to the right of column A in the active row.
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Clears what is being copied.
        
        Range("W6:X6").Copy 'Copies a specific cell/s
        With Selection.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1 - Selection.Column) 'Does everything based off of Column A.
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=22).PasteSpecial 'Pastes X to the right of column A in the active row.
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Clears what is being copied.

        Range("AB6:AD6").Copy 'Copies a specific cell/s
        With Selection.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1 - Selection.Column) 'Does everything based off of Column A.
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=27).PasteSpecial 'Pastes X to the right of column A in the active row.
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Clears what is being copied.

        Range("AH6:AJ6").Copy 'Copies a specific cell/s
        With Selection.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1 - Selection.Column) 'Does everything based off of Column A.
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=33).PasteSpecial 'Pastes X to the right of column A in the active row.
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Clears what is being copied.

        Range("AL6:AO6").Copy 'Copies a specific cell/s
        With Selection.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1 - Selection.Column) 'Does everything based off of Column A.
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=37).PasteSpecial 'Pastes X to the right of column A in the active row.
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Clears what is being copied.

        Range("AR6:BD6").Copy 'Copies a specific cell/s
        With Selection.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1 - Selection.Column) 'Does everything based off of Column A.
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=43).PasteSpecial 'Pastes X to the right of column A in the active row.
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Clears what is being copied.
        
        Range("BF6").Copy 'Copies a specific cell/s
        With Selection.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1 - Selection.Column) 'Does everything based off of Column A.
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=57).PasteSpecial 'Pastes X to the right of column A in the active row.
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Clears what is being copied.
        
        Range("BH6:GH6").Copy 'Copies a specific cell/s
        With Selection.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1 - Selection.Column) 'Does everything based off of Column A.
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=59).PasteSpecial 'Pastes X to the right of column A in the active row.
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Clears what is being copied.
        
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Your data has been reordered and the formulas have been copied down."

End Sub
```

Would greatly appreciate any help, also I suspect the code now isn't well optimised, if you have any suggestions on doing so that would be great too.

No clue why this is happening with just these 1 cell copies, seems very odd to me.

Thanks all.

Comment: Can you please tell what address `Selection` is when you run that code?

Comment: It varies, as the user is going to be dumping in data of 1 to X number of new rows then select those rows then run the code.

[(https://imgur.com/6UBigZz.png)]

Comment: Please read [mcve] then give us one example with input data and output data (screenshots might help a lot). For the example that you give specify the address of `Selection` that was used for this specific example. • We need to be able to reproduce the issue you get.

Comment: uhhh, please don't use comments for data or code. You can [edit] your origanal question for that.

Comment: Apologies, I was having some trouble trying to figure out how to show you some example data. @Pᴇʜ this gif should explain it better, here you can see what it copies from cell U6 it then pastes over U11:Y11 rather than **just** U11.
(https://imgur.com/8XodOT6.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the gif you can clearly see, that the selection changes to the pasted range. So in

```
With Selection.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1 - Selection.Column)
```

you start after every paste with a different `Selection` which has a different size.

So what you should do is

```
Dim ColumnAOfSelection As Rang
Set ColumnAOfSelection = Selection.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1 - Selection.Column)
```

and then use the `ColumnAOfSelection` because this does not change anymore

```
    Range("B6:C6").Copy 'Copies a specific cell/s
    ColumnAOfSelection.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).PasteSpecial 'Pastes X to the right of column A in the active row.
            
    Range("M6:Q6").Copy 'Copies a specific cell/s
    ColumnAOfSelection.Offset(ColumnOffset:=12).PasteSpecial 'Pastes X to the right of column A in the active row.
    
    Range("U6").Copy 'Copies a specific cell/s
    ColumnAOfSelection.Offset(ColumnOffset:=20).PasteSpecial 'Pastes X to the right of column A in the active row.
    
    Range("W6:X6").Copy 'Copies a specific cell/s
    ColumnAOfSelection.Offset(ColumnOffset:=22).PasteSpecial 'Pastes X to the right of column A in the active row.

    Range("AB6:AD6").Copy 'Copies a specific cell/s
    ColumnAOfSelection.Offset(ColumnOffset:=27).PasteSpecial 'Pastes X to the right of column A in the active row.

    Range("AH6:AJ6").Copy 'Copies a specific cell/s
    ColumnAOfSelection.Offset(ColumnOffset:=33).PasteSpecial 'Pastes X to the right of column A in the active row.

    Range("AL6:AO6").Copy 'Copies a specific cell/s
    ColumnAOfSelection.Offset(ColumnOffset:=37).PasteSpecial 'Pastes X to the right of column A in the active row.

    Range("AR6:BD6").Copy 'Copies a specific cell/s
    ColumnAOfSelection.Offset(ColumnOffset:=43).PasteSpecial 'Pastes X to the right of column A in the active row.
    
    Range("BF6").Copy 'Copies a specific cell/s
    ColumnAOfSelection.Offset(ColumnOffset:=57).PasteSpecial 'Pastes X to the right of column A in the active row.
    
    Range("BH6:GH6").Copy 'Copies a specific cell/s
    ColumnAOfSelection.Offset(ColumnOffset:=59).PasteSpecial 'Pastes X to the right of column A in the active row.

    Application.CutCopyMode = False 'you need this only once in the end
```

you might need to adjust the `ColumnOffset` I didn't check them, they might have changed.

Comment: Cheers, I managed to do a similar thing by essentially arranging it as you have in your answer, moving the 1 cell references to the top and then it worked without the extra variables.

However, I suspect your way is more robust so I'll go with your answer. Thanks for your help again. I'm early into my exposure with VBA and rarely need it in my work so have a while to go yet!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it by moving the cell references that only copy 1 cell to the top of the loop.

I also have improved the efficiency by having the 2nd grouping of code that does the copy and pasting to just 1 loop rather than a loop per copy and paste.
This allows it to work off of the original selection which was my intention anyway.